# Changing rgba background color on navbar based on scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a bootsrap fixed navbar at the top of my page. I'd like to gradually and smoothly increase the background-color opacity from 0 up to 0.75 based on the scroll position on the page. How can I do this using jquery?

before scroll

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background: rgba(53,145,204,0);
}
```

after scroll ~500px or better yet 100% of current window size

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background: rgba(53,145,204,0.75);
}
```

Comment: **$(document).scroll(function(){ ... })** see http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used this to achieve a similar effect:

```
    $(function() {
        //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
        var header = $(".fade-transparent");
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 200) {
                header.removeClass('fade-transparent').addClass("fade-background");
            } else {
                header.removeClass("fade-background").addClass('fade-transparent');
            }
        });
    });


.fade-background {

      background-color: #3591cc;
      background-color: rgba(53,145,204,0.75);

      -webkit-transition: background-color 3s;
    transition: background-color 3s;

}

.fade-transparent {

      background-color: transparent;

      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to achieve something like this?

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var dHeight = $(this).height()-$(window).height();
  if (dHeight >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').css('background', 'rgba(53,145,204,' + $(this).scrollTop() / dHeight + ')');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  background: rgba(53, 145, 204, 0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Scroll me...
  </div>
</div>
```