# Nav background depending on school

Tags: jquery, css

I want to, using jQuery, animate `background-color: rgba(46,49,54,0);` to be `background-color: rgba(46,49,54,1);` when you scroll 300px down.

There's already a similar question, but this is with taking the browser height and animating with that height instead of pixels.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27576112/4666639

So can anyone help me animating my navbar background depending on the scroll distance in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if (300 >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').css('background', 'rgba(46,49,54,' + $(this).scrollTop() / 300 + ')');
    } else {
        $('nav').css('background', 'rgba(46,49,54,1)')
    }
});
```

This works. I edited the answer from the other question and removed `var dHeight` and replaced it with static pixels.

**EDIT:** I have added fallback if the page is already scrolled, and then reloaded in the `else {}`

Answer (score 1):

You want to animate the `nav`'s background-color judging by how far the user has scrolled.

You need to store your code inside an event that listens for the scrolling - `$(document).scroll( // code  );` And capture the distance of how far the user has scrolled `$(this).scrollTop()` I presume you know all this.

For example you have your chosen color to be `rgba(46,49,54,0)` and you want to change the color/opacity dynamically depending on that scroll distance.

This is the solution in theory `"rgba(46,49,54,"+ $(this).scrollTop() +")"`.
And this would be it in practice: http://codepen.io/monstrasitix/pen/KVgmML

- I have considered that the scrolling max distance can only be 300px.
- Your picked color

Comment: It would seem that the code breaks when you scroll too fast. I'm on a Mac, and I tried swiping my touchpad as fast as possible, with the result of your code giving the nav `background-color: rgba(46, 49, 54, 0.843137);` it would seem like the best solution is still with a fallback like in my answer. However, I see in your code that you tidied it up using one more variable which might be a good idea so people can understand it easier. **Thank you for your input!**